# GlassMapper not returning item

Tags: glass-mapper

I am using glass mapper and have a Controller Rendering with a DataSource specified.  In the controller I am using the following code

```
        var context = new SitecoreContext();


        var siteSettings = context.GetItem<Alert_Settings>(RenderingContext.Current.Rendering.Item.ID.Guid);
        return View(siteSettings);
```

However siteSettings return null.  Plus what is the difference between

```
RenderingContext.Current.Rendering.Item
```

and

```
RenderingContext.Current.Rendering.DataSource
```

I noticed that .DataSource returns only the guid(string) where as the Rendering.Item returns the complete datasource item.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do the following to get the item back:

```
var siteSettings = this.GetDataSourceItem<Alert_Settings>();
return View(siteSettings);
```

But you must inherit from the `GlassController` to have access to the `GetDataSourceItem` method.  This will return your strongly typed model instead of the guid for your datasource item.  If you don't have the ability to inherit in your current Controller directly from GlassController, you can use a different base controller (which we typically do in our own instances) and have that controller reference the GlassController.

However if you still need to do it without access to the GetDataSourceItem method on the Glass Controller, you could do the following instead:

```
Guid dataSourceId = RenderingContext.Current.Rendering.DataSource;

if (dataSourceId != Guid.Empty) {
    var siteSettings = SitecoreContext.GetItem<ISiteSettings>(dataSourceId);

    return View(siteSettings);
}

return new EmptyViewResult();
```

You can figure this solution out (assuming you didn't already know how to do this) by deconstructing the GlassController on [Github](https://github.com/mikeedwards83/Glass.Mapper/blob/8f4506a14b7c1cd3f9179ed6459741c73fa7ea1a/Source/Glass.Mapper.Sc.Mvc/Web/Mvc/GlassController.cs).  You can see that the T GetDataSourceItem() is passing in a Datasource which is the id returned from `RenderingContext.Current.Rendering.Datasource` into the standard .GetItem method.

Also you asked what exactly is Rendering.Item and how is that different from the datasource on that rendering.  The Rendering.Item is pretty much the same as calling Context.Item which would be the page you are on.  Which the datasource would be the item directly assigned to the current rendering.

Comment: Based on the current situation I can change the inheritance, what is the other way to do this?

Comment: I updated my answer to cover your concerns.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I noticed the following.
Within a controller rendering Rendering.Item and Rendering.DataSource seem to refer to the same thing except one returns a complete item and the other returns only the id.  So its not the same as Context.Item which returns the current page I guess.